# Conversion of date function in sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Trying to convert the date format "2011-03-25 15:00:00.0" to "2011-03-25" in sqlite and getting deep troubles.

When I run this line, it works fine: 
sqlite> select strftime("%Y-%m-%d",'now');
2011-03-16

But when I run this line, it loses out : 
sqlite> select strftime("%Y-%m-%d",'date_start') from test;

What am I doing wrong in this?

Sagos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes from `date_start`

```
~ e$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table test (dt);
sqlite> insert into test values (22222222);
sqlite> select strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dt) from test;
5613-14-26
sqlite> insert into test values (2222222);
sqlite> select strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dt) from test;
5613-14-26
1372-02-19
sqlite> 

sqlite> select substr('2011-03-22 08:00:00.0',1,19);
2011-03-22 08:00:00

sqlite> insert into test values ('2011-03-22 08:00:00.0');
sqlite> select strftime("%Y-%m-%d",substr(dt,1,19)) from test;
5613-14-26
1372-02-19
2011-03-22
```

Comment: select strftime("%Y-%m-%d",date_start) from test; Still it does not work. -- Sagos

Comment: Ohh I have spaces after each line. Check my example. How to remove the new line and tab spaces from it in sqlite ?

Comment: I am trying to replace the new line with no space but still not correct: sqlite> select distinct replace(date_start,"\n","") from test;

Comment: Note that strings in SQL are quoted with ' not " -- also, backslash escapes won't work, you have to include the literal character. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html for other options; I added an example using substr() in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you Doug. It worked that way. You really saved my time of changing the entire data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite> select distinct date_start from test;

        2011-03-22 08:00:00.0

        2011-03-22 09:00:00.0
```