# Trying to trim the data in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to trim the data using trim but still it does not trim: it shows new line and space after each line.

Am I doing wrong or is it not possible or do I have to use any other functions?
Any help greatly appreciated.

```
sqlite> select distinct trim(date_start) from test;
    2011-03-22 08:00:00.0
    2011-03-22 09:00:00.0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion of date function in sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328990/conversion-of-date-function-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the characters you're trying to trim are spaces? What you're doing should work:

```
sqlite> create table test (date_start text);
sqlite> insert into test values ('    2011-03-22 08:00:00.0');
sqlite> insert into test values ('    2011-03-22 09:00:00.0');
sqlite> select * from test;
    2011-03-22 08:00:00.0
    2011-03-22 09:00:00.0
sqlite> select distinct trim(date_start) from test;
2011-03-22 08:00:00.0
2011-03-22 09:00:00.0
```

Comment: actually, I am trying to parse the data and then store in the database. so when I look at the data in the array list it shows : "\n\t\t\t2011-03-22 08:00:00.0". Hence it shows as spaces while I run the select query and I am really not getting how to resolve it.

Comment: `TRIM` only trims spaces.  You need to specify what characters to trim. For example, if you want tab, CR, LF and space, use `trim(date_start, X'090d0a20')`

Comment: For anyone else that stumbles across this one, if you are using UTF16 you will need `trim(date_start, X'09000d000a002000')`

Comment: Thanks David, you should post that as an answer